# Should this run in parallel?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I was under impression that Haskell would run a program like the one below in parallel (each `a,b,c` combination would get pushed through all the `filter`s independently).

```
main = print $ 
       map (\(a,b,c) -> a * b * c) $
       filter (\(a,b,c) -> a^2 + b^2 == c^2) $
       filter (\(a,b,c) -> a + b + c == 1000) $
       filter (\(a,b,c) -> a < b && b < c) $
       [(a,b,c) | a <- [0..1000], b <- [0..1000], c <- [0..1000]]
```

But when I run the program I can see that only one of the four threads on my machine are utilised.

Why is my expectation wrong?

Comment: Running the code using `runhaskell` provided by `Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.10.2`

Comment: Have you considered using line-breaks? (They won't help the parallelism, but they will help everyone reading your code.)

Comment: Haskell does not automatically parallelize computations. Firstly it must be enabled by command line options (`-threaded` or something like that) but more importantly you have to tell it which things to evaluate in parallel, which at the most basic level corresponds to `par` and `parSeq` in `Control.Parallel`.

Comment: As a side note, this is probably a bad example.. doing the filters "in parallel" will not help you, if you do them sequentially then ghc will optimize all the filters and the map into one wicked fast loop. If you seperate them with `par` I don't think it could do this optimization.

Comment: The sort of parallelism you *want* here is best left to your friendly CPU. The main thing you should do here is add a type signature to force those numbers to have type `Int` instead of defaulting to `Integer`. I also think the code would be a lot cleaner if you fused all the filters into one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Should this run in parallel?

No, because GHC doesn't add parallelism by default (see below). Also, parallelism isn't a convenient orbital cannon that just blasts away any kind of problem (see further below).

> Why is my expectation wrong?

First of all, using `runhaskell` is mostly the same as using GHCi: it doesn't use optimization since `-O` con­flicts with `--interactive`, it doesn't give you additional RTS options, and you cannot use all those nice compiler flags that give you a little bit more juice.

But even if you compile your code with a threaded runtime, you won't end up with a faster ex­e­cu­ta­ble:

```
$ ghc --make -O2 -rtsopts -with-rtsopts -N -threaded SO.hs 
$ .\SO +RTS -s
[31875000]
   2,863,269,440 bytes allocated in the heap
       1,135,584 bytes copied during GC
         100,016 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          31,152 bytes maximum slop
               2 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      5471 colls,  5471 par    0.266s   0.283s     0.0001s    0.0126s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     1 par    0.000s   0.001s     0.0004s    0.0007s

  Parallel GC work balance: 0.00% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N2)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time   20.328s  ( 21.671s elapsed)     <-------
  GC      time    0.266s  (  0.284s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time   20.609s  ( 21.956s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    140,852,608 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  98.7% of total user, 92.7% of total elapsed
```

That's because GHC doesn't add parallelism automatically. While it would be nice to just flip a switch and be done, parallelism can cause a pretty high overhead if done wrong. For example, if `f :: Int -> T` is a complex function, then running `head $ filter p $ parallelMap f [1..100]` is probably fine. But calling `head $ filter p $ parallelMap f [1..]` isn't anymore. After all, Haskell is lazy.

## Speeding things up without parallelism

Now that you know why there's no automagical parallelism in Haskell, what can you do to speed up your program? First of all, structure it:

```
triples :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
triples = filter pythagoras . filter smaller . filter sum1000 $ ts
  where 
    pythagoras (a,b,c) = a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 == c ^ 2
    sum1000    (a,b,c) = a + b + c == 1000
    smaller    (a,b,c) = a < b && b < c

    ts = [(a,b,c) | a <- [0..1000], b <- [0..1000], c <- [0..1000]]

main :: IO ()
main = print $ map (\(a,b,c) -> a * b * c) $ triples
```

Now, this is a lot easier to read than your previous program. Hm. You generate a list and then apply three filters afterwards. Wait a second. `sum1000` and `smaller` seem off. For any given range, the number of triples that fulfil `smaller` is usually relatively small, and for any given `a` and `b`, there is only *one* `c` that fulfils `sum1000`!

We can fuse both conditions together to get the following ones on `a`, `b` and `c` directly:

- `a` can never be larger than `332`, since we cannot split `1000 - 333` into `b` and `c` so that `smaller` still holds (`667 = 333 + 334`)
- `b` is always greater than `a`
- `b` can never be larger than `(1000 - a) / 2`, otherwise there's no suitable `c`
- `c` is always `1000 - a - b`, but there is no `c` for `a = 0` and `b = 500`.

We end up with the following list instead:

```
triples :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
triples = filter pythagoras . filter smaller . filter sum1000 $ ts
  where
    pythagoras (a,b,c) = a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 == c ^ 2
    sum1000    (a,b,c) = a + b + c == 1000
    smaller    (a,b,c) = a < b && b < c

    ts = [(a,b,c) | a <- [0..332]
                  , b <- [a+1 .. (1000 - a)`div` 2]
                  , let c = 1000 - a - b]

-- Old list for documentation
--  ts = [(a,b,c) | a <- [0..1000], b <- [0..1000], c <- [0..1000]]
```

You could also remove the filters, but then don't forget the check for `b < c`.

This is a lot faster, since we're now using an *O(n²)* approach instead of an *O(n³)* one. `runhaskell SO.hs` will finish after 2 seconds on my PC, and if we actually compile it, we end up with an almost immediately finishing executable:

```
$ ghc --make -O2 SO.hs
$ ./SO +RTS -s
[31875000]
         104,960 bytes allocated in the heap
           1,752 bytes copied during GC
          42,664 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
          18,776 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0         0 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0005s    0.0005s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)  <----------------
  GC      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.000s  (  0.003s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.0%  (13.9% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    0 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity 100.0% of total user, 0.0% of total elapsed
```

## TL;DR

Decreasing the work to a minuscule of its original size always trumps running far too much work in parallel.

Comment: The most amazing answer I have ever received on SO, thank you very much! I didn't do any optimization of the problem size so that I can talk about parallelism alone, but I get the point about reducing it.

Comment: I'm a Haskell beginner and the readability of your code is awesome. Will give me something to aim for.